# Program runs in compiler but returns runtime error in online judge

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve this problem on this online judge: https://a2oj.com/ladder?ID=3 (see problem below) using the following code. It runs successfully on the compiler but returns a runtime error on the online judge.

**EDIT: Code after changing loop conditions**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct count {
    int number;
    int repetitions;
};

bool sortByNumber(const struct count &lhs, const struct count &rhs) { 
    return lhs.number < rhs.number;
}

int main() {
    vector <int> input;
    int n = 0;
    do {
        cin>>n;
        input.push_back(n);
    } while (n != 0);

    struct count x[101] = {NULL};

    for (int j = 0; j < input.size(); j++) {
        int tracker = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < input.size(); z++) {
            if (input[j] != x[z].number) {
                tracker++;
            }
        }
        if (tracker == input.size()) {
            x[j].number = input[j];
        }
    }

    sort(x, x+101, sortByNumber);

    for (int y = 0; y < 101; y++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < input.size(); w++) {
            if (x[y].number == input[w]) {
                x[y].repetitions++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int v = 0; v < 101; v++) {
        if (x[v].number != 0) {
            cout << x[v].number << " " << x[v].repetitions << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming so I apologize if the answer is obvious and I can't see it. I've researched causes of runtime errors and I can't see any memory leaks, logic errors, or divisions by zero. The only thing I can think of is that it's a segmentation fault caused by the many nested loops (this code uses a lot more memory and running time than the other programs I submitted to the online judge), but I can't think of another way to solve this problem. Any ideas, even just about where to look, would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT: Problem**
Problem Statement:
Amgad got a job as a Cashier in a big store, where he gets thousands of dollars everyday. As a cashier, he must count the amount of each dollar bill (banknote) he has at the end of each day.

Amgad wants you to help him by writing a computer program so Amgad can just enter the amount of each bill and you count each bill separately.

Input Format:
one or more positive numbers ending by zero each number is between 1 and 100 inclusive

Output Format:
print each number only once in one line followed by the number of repetitions

Sample Input:
100
20
5
2
10
20
5
5
20
100
10
2
2
10
5
0

Sample Output:
2 3
5 4
10 3
20 3
100 2

Comment: _It runs successfully on the compiler_ It doesn't **run** on the compiler. Compiler only compiles it, and your computer executes compiled executable. Runtime error means - it compiled successfully, but threw an error, while executing. Did you try **stepping through** your code in a debugger?

Comment: As A2 online judge requires login can you please summarize the statement?

Comment: What is the runtime error it is throwing.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thanks for pointing that out, edited the question to include the problem statement!

Comment: Try to see if you program doesn't crash because of BadMemoryAllocation, IntegerOverflow, or any other reasons during when the program is being executed.

Comment: @rikola It doesn't say

Comment: The link you've given is password protected. Please list the inputs and outputs so we can try to establish what's wrong. Have you tried also (a) running through a debugger or (b) adding trace logging to establish where at runtime this fails?

Comment: You seem to be indexing `x` on your input sample size, but `x` is a fixed array of 8 elements. Your input seems to have more than eight elements.

Comment: Also, I suspect this "Online Judge" thing is testing this program against much larger datasets which would not be replicated on your local machine unless you had a more extreme test.

Comment: This is as good a time as any to learn about `std::map`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm familiar with the data structure but have never actually used it. Will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Component10 mentioned, your array is of a fixed size. Add an integer called `count` that increments every time a new number is popped out of the input. Change all the integer literal references to `8` to `counter`.

Comment: I can't seem to initialize an array of variable size, as in:

`const struct x[count] = {NULL};`

on the online judge, and when I don't initialize it it fills with garbage.

Comment: Yeah you need to dynamically allocate memory in C++. You then need to release it after the data is no longer useful. Since the data is coming in over the input stream, there is not a good way to pre-measure the `count` of numbers before they are already popped out of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

If `input` contains more than 101 elements, the conditions

```
if (tracker == 8) {
    x[j].number = input[j];
}
```

and

```
if (input[j] != x[z].number) {
    tracker++;
}
```

Are invoking undefined behavior for any `j` value above 100, due to out-of-bounds access of array `x` elements. Both `z`, and `j` are looped to `input.size()`, which can be higher than 101.

Undefined behavior can manifest itself in many ways. Runtime error is one of those possibilities.

Comment: @Component 10 Thank you! x isn't the input array but the array in which I'm singling out banknote values and sorting them (e.g. 2, 5, etc.). I've tried fixing it at 101 (according to the question banknote values can be from 1 to 100 inclusive) and 8 (since it's in dollars, and there are 8 banknote values in the US $). I see what you mean about putting 8 in the conditions, and I've changed that, but it still returns a runtime error (edited code in post accordingly).

Comment: @LaraAasem Still.. The problem is the same. If `input` contains more elements that `101` - you are invoking undefined behavior, due to the same reason - indexing out of bounds.

Comment: @LaraAasem Updated answer to take your updated code into account. As you can see, now there are 2 spots where you are invoking undefined behavior, instead of 1, as was previously.